# Random(seed).nextInt always generate 0 for the first number generated

Tags: java

here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandGen 
{
    Random rd;
    static final int SIZE = 1;
    int[] result = new int[SIZE];
    public RandGen(int seed)
    {
        rd = new Random(seed);
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE-1;i++)
        {
            result[i] = rd.nextInt((int) Math.pow(10,9)+1);
        }
    }
}
```

you can change the SIZE constant for bigger array size, however the Random rd.nextInt will always generate the first number to 0.

Comment: What value are you passing as the seed?

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting the seed?

Comment: no matter what seed i past it will give me 0

Comment: @paradox: That's because the loop body never runs, which you'd've seen if you'd used the debugger to step through the code. When you have a trivial problem like this, reach for the debugger. It's your friend.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder change the SIZE to 2 or arbitrary number it will give you 0 whatsoever

Comment: @paradox: No, it won't. It will give you `0` for the *last* entry in `random`, but not the first if `SIZE` is greater than 1, because you never set it to anything else, for the reason jhhoff02 explained. (Which, again, you'd see with a debugger.) ([Proof](http://ideone.com/cqeZgr))

Comment: omg my problem was so stupid, i see it now!

Comment: @paradox As your puzzle is solved, don't forget to accept your preferred solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the problem is with your `for` loop, your logical test basically says "As long as 0 is less than 0" increment `i`. `SIZE` is 1 and you put `SIZE-1` which equals 0.

**Edit:** As mentioned by **T.J. Crowder** and **JB Nizet** below, the `for` loop never sets the value of the last element in the array because it would only run for `SIZE-1` elements, and the loop is never entered.

Comment: ...and so `random[0]` is never set to any value because the body of the loop never runs, and so it keeps its default value of `0`, hence seeming to get `0` as the first random number.

Comment: change the SIZE to 2 or arbitrary number it will give you 0 whatsoever, btw the value of seed is also arbitrary.

Comment: @paradox No, it won't. The **last** element in the array is always 0, because the last element is never set, because the loop goes until SIZE -1 instead of SIZE.

Comment: @MouseEvent: Good point, they do say that. They're wrong ([proof](http://ideone.com/cqeZgr)), but they do say that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems I see here:

1. As outline by the other answer, your loop condition is "off by one"; in its current version, that loop is **never** entered; and thus the array simply stays with it "initial" value (all zeros)
2. When you are calling the code using the same seed all the time, well ... then there is no "randomness" in there. Then the sequence will **always** be the same. That is point of using seeds!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array of size `SIZE`, its positions are on the interval `0..SIZE-1`. Then to go through all the values in the array, the `for`loop should be `for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){}`. Since you have `int i=0;i<SIZE-1`and `SIZE` is equal to 1, the program never enters that for loop. In case you had a bigger `SIZE`, the for loop would never touch the last index of your array.